# change logo default notification email laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I´m traying chenge logo in notification email with laravel 8.

first i published all theme:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

and in `header.blade` into folder `mail/html` i´m doing this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/image_default.png') }}" class="logo" alt="Laravel Logo">
```

my image it´s in `public/img`

and i´m sending  my email ok, but in gmail my logo img it´s broken. I´m using a `vhost in localhost`

in my email, img route it´s:

googleURL**http://laravellimpio/img/image_default.png**

i checked my `asset` in other `blade` and i can show my img ok. I don´t know if i have a problem with my code or it´s for used localhost.

Thanks for help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<tr>
<td class="header">
<a href="{{ $url }}" style="display: inline-block;">
@if (trim($slot) === 'Laravel')
<img src="https://laravel.com/img/notification-logo.png" class="logo" alt="Laravel Logo">
@else
<img src="{{ asset('img/image_default.png') }}" class="logo" alt="My logo">
@endif
</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see there is a conditional statement checking if the app name is equal to Laravel, change the name of your app from the `env file` and then remove the `{{ $slot }}` and use your own path. You need to change the app name so that it skips the first portion of the statement and selects the space between the `@else`.